Distribution of sample standard deviation
Noting this question, it is known that the sum of independent identically distributed gaussian random variables is a Noncentral chi-squared distribution.
It is also known that the sample distribution is a normal distribution:
$$
\bar{X} = \frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_k}{k}
$$
That is great and all, but what about:
$$
Z = \sqrt{\frac{(X_1-\bar{X})^2+(X_2-\bar{X})^2+\dots+(X_k-\bar{X})^2}{k}}
$$
Is this also a known distribution with well known properties?

Obscure. Who are $\overline{X}_i?$

@LetacGérard fair point, clarified.

Not really.....

A "noncentral chi-squared distribution" comes from the sum of squares of $k$ iid $N(\mu,1)$ distributed random variables. If $\mu=0$ then you get an ordinary chi-squared distribution, with $k$ degrees of freedom. The square root of a noncentral chi-squared distributed random variable has a "noncentral chi distribution".
But your $Z$ does not have a non-central distribution even if $\mu\not=0$, because you still have $\mathbb E[X_i-\bar X]=0$.  Furthermore $\sum\limits_i (X_i-\bar X) =0$, reducing the degrees of freedom.
If the iid $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $\frac{k}{\sigma^2}Z^2 = \frac{(X_1-\bar{X})^2+(X_2-\bar{X})^2+\dots+(X_k-\bar{X})^2}{\sigma^2}$ has an ordinary chi-squared distribution, with $k-1$ degrees of freedom. Since it has an expectation of $k-1$, it is often divided by $k-1$ rather than $k$ to give the sample variance using Bessel's correction.
So $\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sigma}Z = \sqrt{\frac{(X_1-\bar{X})^2+(X_2-\bar{X})^2+\dots+(X_k-\bar{X})^2}{\sigma^2}}$ has an ordinary chi distribution, with $k-1$ degrees of freedom.
You might then say $Z$ has a scaled chi distribution.
